# Robotic arm for university student

Tags: robotic-arm

Can anybody recommend a robotic arm to be possibly coupled with VR to be used for educational purposes for university students within a bucket of about 15000€?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* drSlump, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a [bit of a list](http://petercorke.com/wordpress/low-cost-robots-for-hobbyists-and-teaching) of what's available for teaching robots.

Comment: You should copy and paste your bit of a list here as linking to a link that links to another link which might end up dead someday will make your answer useless to people in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The default decision would be a UR5. It is a bit out or your range, but it could be worth to check with UR if they give you a university discount. Main advantage is the huge user base, rather good support in ROS and easy things like following waypoints can be done in python within hours of unpackaging.

Comment: How much out of range?

Comment: They are normally a bit over 20k Euro, but that's for commercial buyers.